# Orbeon : how to set the href of a <xhtml:a> tag, based on the current node in a <xforms:repeat>?

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to set a href attribute of a  tag, based on the value of a leaf of the current node in a xforms:repeat. I've tried different syntax, but can't make it work. This is my last try (with a xforms:var). NOTE : the iteration and the list are ok, just the href is not (null pointer exception).

```
<xforms:repeat id="sous_menu_branches" nodeset="./Branches/Branche">
    <xhtml:li>
         <xforms:var name="brancheId" value="./BrancheId"/>
         <xhtml:a href="/notes-saisie/?brancheId={$brancheId}">         
             <xforms:output ref="Nom" mediatype="text/html"/>
         </xhtml:a>
     </xhtml:li>
</xforms:repeat>
```

Actually, when I try to use xforms:var in my view (view.xsl), I always got a java null pointer error. As example, in the code snippet bellow, the first xforms:output throw an exception, but not the second one (which is supposed to access the same value) :

```
 <xforms:repeat id="sous_menu_branches" nodeset="./Branches/Branche">
     <xhtml:li>
         <xforms:var name="current-item" value="."/>
         <xforms:output id="my-count" ref="$current-item/Nom"/>
         <xhtml:a href="/notes-saisie/?brancheId=888">        
             <xforms:output ref="./Nom" mediatype="text/html"/>
         </xhtml:a>
     </xhtml:li>
 </xforms:repeat>
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which version of Orbeon Forms you are using, but I suspect you are using one which doesn't yet support `xforms:var`. Try using `xxforms:variable` instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You're probably right : I'm using version 3.9. Didn't noticed that `xforms:var` is "new". I finally switched to `xsl:variable` instead, but I'll give a try to `xxforms:variable`, just to be sure.

Comment: `xsl:variable` and XForms variable are processed at different times. The former is processed by XSLT, the latter by XForms. XSLT variables are processed only upon page load, XForms variables are updated as the user interacts with a form.

Comment: Huhu, I see... In my page, I have an instance containing a parameter of the current url (using a bind and `xxforms:get-request-parameter()`. Is there a way to use this value in a `xsl:variable` to drive the xslt processor (i.e. selecting a nodeset, building a table and so on) ? Or is there a way to get the url parameter in another way to make it available to the xslt transform ?

Comment: PS. I would prefer to stay with the xslt transform, so make available to the xslt processor the url parameters of the request. I've read the orbeon doc about it (with the default submission), but I don't understand how to make it work :-(

Comment: PS2. I've also tried to replace `xforms:var` with `xxforms:variable` in my first code example, but I still got an error from the parser : **Variable brancheId has not been declared**. Is the following syntax not correct ? `<xforms:variable name="brancheId" select="BrancheId"/>  <xhtml:a href="/notes-saisie/?brancheId={$brancheId}">`

Comment: To your PS2: the thing to understand is that you have first XSLT processing (and BTW we at Orbeon try to limit that because that adds complexity, as you are witnessing right now) and second XForms processing. IF you do XSLT processing, THEN XSLT processes Attribute Value Templates (AVTs) first. If you want an AVT to be handled by XForms instead of XSLT, you need to escape it, e.g. `brancheId={{$brancheId}}"`.

Comment: XSLT doesn't have access to XForms anything. XSLT is purely a preprocessing step for XForms here. So XSLT doesn't have access to values in your instances. You can feed XSLT with URL parameters, using the `oxf:request` processor or the PFC. But it's way more complicated than with XForms.

Comment: Ok, I think a got it. Once again, thank you very much for the precision of your answers and for the time you've spend to write them :-)